# Allow any user with specific uid to manager an entire OU

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a domain (let's call it `dc=example,dc=org`)

The domain has a branch (`ou=users,ou=ftp,ou=services,dc=k9999,dc=z9999,dc=infra,dc=example,dc=org`).

There's a `simpleSecurityObject` in this domain (`uid=admin,ou=managers,ou=ftp,ou=services,dc=k9999,dc=z9999,dc=infra,dc=example,dc=org`).

I need the `uid=admin,***` user to have full (`manage`) access to the `ou=users,***` branch, so I added the following `olcAccess` record:

```
to
  dn.subtree="ou=users,ou=ftp,ou=services,dc=k9999,dc=z9999,dc=infra,dc=example,dc=org"
by
  dn.exact="uid=admin,ou=managers,ou=ftp,ou=services,dc=k9999,dc=z9999,dc=infra,dc=example,dc=org"
```

It has added to the default set of rules:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth manage by * break
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by dn="cn=a
 dmin,dc=example,dc=org" write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {2}to * by self read by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" write by
 * none
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="ou=users,ou=ftp,ou=services,dc=k9999,dc=z9999,dc=
 infra,dc=example,dc=org" by dn.exact="uid=admin,ou=managers,ou=ftp,ou=servi
 ces,dc=k9999,dc=z9999,dc=infra,dc=example,dc=org" manage
```

But something seems to be wrong. When I run `ldapsearch -D uid=admin,ou=managers,ou=ftp,ou=services,dc=k9999,dc=z9999,dc=infra,dc=example,dc=org -W -b ou=users,ou=ftp,ou=services,dc=k9999,dc=z9999,dc=infra,dc=example,dc=org`, I get the following result:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=users,ou=ftp,ou=services,dc=k9999,dc=z9999,dc=infra,dc=example,dc=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
command terminated with exit code 32
```

The object is available and `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org` can see it without any difficulties, so it seems that my access rule is wrong. But what exactly it is?

It seems that the default rule #2 (`{2} to * by self read by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" write by * none`) fires up earlier than the rule I added. Does that mean that I should **always** add my custom rules before it?

And why does this rule has `by * none`? Doesn't it contradict the [OpenLDAP documentation](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html)?

> The default access control policy is allow read by all clients

It seems that rule #2 (I mean this one:

```
to * 
by self read
by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" write
by * none
```

) isn't "default" at all. I've just found another instance of OpenLDAP (I deployed it about 4 years ago). This instance (2.4.40) doesn't have such rule at all. It seems that it has not been added by OpenLDAP itself, it rather has been added manually by someone or something else. Am I right? Doesn't OpenLDAP have such rule by default?

Comment: If you're serious about delegated administration, dynamic views for service etc. you might want to have a closer look at [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com). Being the author I'm biased of course.

Answer (score 0):

General advice:

- Order matters!
  This general statement applies to order of ACLs and order of the <who> clauses.
- Each ACL implicitly ends with a `by * none` which means control flows stops there.
- Debug ACLs by running slapd with `loglevel stats ACL`
- Read [slapd.access(5)](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd.access) very carefully and not only once!

E.g. AFAICS in your example ACL #2 masks ACL #3.

Do yourself a favour: Instead of inventing this wheel ad-hoc again have a closer look at my [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com). It has many ACLs for enforcing delegated administration and limiting visibility based on a clear data model. Being the author I'm biased of course. Otherwise I know very well how much work is in front of you if you follow that route...